# Injecting presenters with MVP/Dagger 2

Tags: android, mvp, dagger-2

I've been learning about DI and Dagger 2 recently, and I feel like I'm ending up with more boilerplate than what I started with. My setup includes

- `AppComponent` -- provides `Application`, `Resources` and other networking-related stuff. `@Singleton` Scoped.
- `Feature1Component`, `Feature2Component`.... -- provide repositories used across screens. `@Feature` scoped, subcomponents of `AppComponent`. Has 'plus' methods for screen components.
- `Screen1Component`, `Screen2Component`... -- this is where the feeling of boilerplate comes in - each screen component just has an 'inject' method for the Fragment/Activity that is being used to depict the screen. Subcomponent of `FeatureXComponent`. Each corresponding module ends up looking just like so:

  ```
  @Module
  public class Screen1Module
  {
      private final Screen1Contract.View view;

      public Screen1Module(Screen1Contract.View view)
      {
          this.view = view;
      }

      @Provides
      public Screen1Contract.View provideView()
      {
          return view;
      }
  }
  ```

So as a result, for each screen, I end up writing a Component and Module since I can only call the following:

```
((MyApplication) getActivity().getApplication())
                .getFeature1Component()
                .newScreen1Component(new Screen1Module(this))
                .inject(this);
```

when I'm initializing my view `(Activity or Fragment)`, for the benefit of injecting just the presenter.

Is there a way to do this which does not involve as much boilerplate? I was hoping to inject screens at the "Feature" level, but I guess that isn't really possible since screens have a shorter life cycle than features.

Comment: For the particular module you're showing you can do all this with `@Bindsinstance` on your component builder, see here https://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.11/dagger/BindsInstance.html

Answer (score 0):

This is why `dagger-android` is born since dagger 2.10. It simplifies injection of Android core types.

`@ContributesAndroidInjector` replaces subcomponents. `DaggerActivity` and others get rid of `getComponent()....inject(this)`

[its official doc](https://google.github.io/dagger/android)

[and a pretty good article I found recently](https://proandroiddev.com/how-to-android-dagger-2-10-2-11-butterknife-mvp-part-1-eb0f6b970fd)